# Can't find the bug in the program to print the input lines longer than 80 characters

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PRINT 80

int get_line(char k[], int lim);

int main(){

    int len;
    char line[PRINT];

    while((len = get_line(line, PRINT)) > 0){
        if(len > PRINT){
            printf("%s", line);
        }
    }    
}


int get_line(char k[], int lim){

    int i, c;

    for (i =0; i < lim-1 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c!= '\n'; ++i){
        k[i] = c;
    }

    if(c == '\n'){
        k[i] = c;
        ++i;
     } 

    k[i] = '\0';

    return i;

}
```

The above stated code is written to print all the input lines with length greater than 80 characters, but it is not printing anything. The code compiles without any errors. I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    if(c=='\n'){
        k[i] = c;
        ++i;
  }
```

By incrementing `i` you have array out of bound access and your question itself leads to undefined behavior which is storing more than 80 characters in an array which can hold 80 characters.

```
char line[80];
```

Make array size more than 80 characters like

```
char line[200];
```

Then try to do what you are doing and add a check before writing to array `line`

```
if(i > 200)
{
   printf("Array can't hold this character\n");
   // break or return
}
```

Your `lim` should be `200`.

Answer (score 2):

You initialize your array to 80, but you're trying to print strings with more than 80 characters so you will always print blank because you will never have the scenario (nor can you store more than 80 chars). Change the initialization for `k[]` and `line[]` to something larger than 80, or use vectors for automatic re-sizing.